# Stuck in Hangman Game

Tags: java, string

i am currently learning Java programming and we are required to make a Basic Hangman Game, no Graphic interface, just main and the fewer methods possible.

So here is the thing :

I did a method that allows me to choose between different topics, each topic with 5 words or group of words on it, and it randomly chooses one of them and assigns it to a String variable "word", the one i'll be working with.

Then there is a Method that creates a String "HiddenWord", just Replacing characters by ' * ' and keeps the spaces between words.

The problem is that i dont know how to input a char "Letter" and, replace that Letter in the Hidden Word, resolving the Hidden word step by step.

I will provide my code, but it is in Spanish so i'll translate some of the key words (Did you noticed my Awesome English skills uh?)

`HideWord` method  ( no probs here, I think , maybe the spacing between words should be done in other way) :

```
public String hideWord(String word)
{
    String hiddenWord ="";
    for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++)
    {
        if(word.charAt(i)==' ')
        {
            hiddenWord+=' ';
        }
        else
        {
            hiddenWord+='*';
        }
    }
    return hiddenWord;
}
```

I've deleted the uninteresting and easy parts from the `main` method knowingly.

```
main ()
{

    Ahorcado objeto=new Ahorcado();

    //Example word, since the full code is really long

    String word = "Hello World";
    int life;


    String hiddenWord=objeto.hideWord(word);

    System.out.println("Game just Started\n");

    System.out.println(palabraOculta); //Hello world -> ***** *****

    char letter;

    boolean resolved=false;

    do
    {

        System.out.println("Input a letter");
        letter=objeto.teclado.next().charAt(0);

        //Intentionally left almost Blank because every try did a weird Pyramid thing or just crash
        for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++)
        {
            if(letter==word.charAt(i))
            {
            }
        }
        if(hiddenWord.equals(word))
        {
            resolved=true;
        }
        objeto.life--;
    }
    while(objeto.vidas>=0&&resolved==false);
}
```

Well, that's it, sorry for my horrible Grammar and my poor Java, I will provide more parts of the code if needed.

Comment: Yeah sorry, i've been editing it to avoid all methods so i must have made some mistakes, that one its just a typo :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do once you have found that a letter is in the word, just replace the * character in the index where you found the letter in the original word :

```
 for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++)
 {
     if(letter==word.charAt(i))
     {
         char[] wordCharsArray = hiddenWord.toCharArray();
         wordCharsArray[i] = letter;
         hiddenWord= String.valueOf(wordCharsArray);
     }
 }
```

I am not sure but there might be a more efficient way to replace a character in a string but this should work for you.

Comment: Oh, that...worked :D never worked with .toCharArray() before but it looks perfect for this Hangman thing, thank you so much! .

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency, I would simply use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
    do{    
        System.out.println("Input a letter");
        letter=objeto.teclado.next().charAt(0);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++){
             if(letter == word.charAt(i)){
                 sb.append(word.charAt(i));
             } else {
                sb.append(hiddenWord.charAt(i));
             }
        }
        hiddenWord = sb.toString();
        resolved = hiddenWord.equals(word);
        objeto.life--;
    } while(objeto.vidas>=0 && !resolved); //resolved == false could be simplified to !resolved
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but, there are so many thing on your code that i dont even understand yet...any change that i made on my code would require another post here to fix it if i use your code but i really apreciate your help :D

Comment: @DanielSimon This is not very different from your code, a part using a `StringBuilder` to build the `String`. What part don't you understand exactly?